# Java RegEx with variable character range

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I need to check if all characters of a string are in a specific character range.

I know I can check with the regular expression:

```
input.matches("[a-z]+");
```

if a string only contains letters from `a` to `z`.
But how can I do it if the character range is defined by an given interface?  For example, the interface `xxx`
has the attribute

```
xxx.FIRST_CHAR = 'a';
```

and

```
xxx.LAST_CHAR = 'z';
```

but the attributes can be changed.

Is there any way to use variable characters in regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may concatenate regex patterns same as concatenating strings using `+` operator.

```
str.matches(xxx.FIRST_CHAR + "[a-z]*" + xxx.LAST_CHAR);
```